# Passing a list of columns to Order function in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R with large number of columns. I need to order by several columns. Typically I can order with a code such as this

```
someData[with(someData, order(col1, col2)),]
```

However, I have a list of columns to sort:

```
sortcols= c('col1','col2','col3',...)
```

I need to sort the data by passing in the sortcols to the order function. How can I achieve this.

Comment: `with(someData, do.call(order,mget(sortcols)) )`, I think.

Comment: You can do it using `dplyr` by doing `someData %>% arrange_(.dots=sortcols)`.

Comment: @frank your solution works good for me. Do you want to answer the question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
someData[ with( someData, do.call(order, mget(sortcols)) ), ]
```